# How to make UITextView Text Clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, clickable

I have several strings joined by `/` and placed in `UITextview`. I have to make each of the strings before the `/` clickable. I don't know the specific string or its range. I used a tap gesture recognizer to give me the touched word but I want the whole string. As an the example, my string is "ABC-1234/DEF-1234/ghi-9874". But when I tap it, I either get "abc" or "ghi". How to get the whole string?

Below is my current code, which doesn't work as intended:

```
UITextView *textView =  (UITextView *)tapRecognizer.view;
CGPoint location = [tapRecognizer locationInView:textView];    
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:position];

UITextRange *textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
// NSString *tappedWord = [textView textInRange:textRange];
```

I tried using `NSScanner` but I was also not successful. Below is the code using `NSScanner`. It gives me only the last value:

```
NSString *plainString = self.SelectedTextView.attributedText.string;
NSMutableArray* substrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc]initWithString:plainString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"/" intoString:nil];

while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString* substring = nil;
    [scanner scanString:@"/" intoString:nil];
    NSString* space = @" ";
    if ([scanner scanUpToString:space intoString:&substring]) {
        [substrings addObject:substring];
    }
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"/" intoString:nil];
}

NSLog(@"%@",substrings);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: yes,I solved it wait i post the answers @Abdul Jamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the string is assigned to textview at that time i called one method which calculates the elements in selected textview

```
-(void)ElementsInSelectedTextView
{
    localizedStringPieces = [NSArray new];
     localizedStringPieces = [_SelectedTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
     arrMinMax = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <[localizedStringPieces count]; i++) {
        NSString * str =[localizedStringPieces objectAtIndex:i];
        NSUInteger length = count + str.length-1;
        NSMutableDictionary * tempdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [tempdic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:count] forKey:@"MinValue"];
        [tempdic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:length] forKey:@"MaxValue"];
        [arrMinMax addObject:tempdic];
        count = length +1;

    }

}
```

Add tap Gesture on textView (here _selectedtextview is my object name of uitextview)

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *lblTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SelectedProductTextViewDetected:)];
    [_SelectedTextView addGestureRecognizer:lblTapRecognizer];
    // prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
    lblTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

In THe selector method add the following code

```
- (void)SelectedProductTextViewDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
 NSUInteger characterIndex;
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = _SelectedTextView.layoutManager;
    CGPoint location = [tapRecognizer locationInView:_SelectedTextView];
    characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location
                                           inTextContainer:_SelectedTextView.textContainer
                  fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];

    NSString * strValue;
    for (int j = 0; j<[arrMinMax count]; j++) {
        if (characterIndex >=[[[arrMinMax objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"MinValue"] integerValue]  && characterIndex <=[[[arrMinMax objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"MaxValue"] integerValue]) {
            strValue = [localizedStringPieces objectAtIndex:j];
            SelectedProductIndex = j;
        }
    }
 _SelectedTextView.text = strValue;
     [self.SelectedTextView layoutIfNeeded];
    _SelectedTextView.editable = NO;
}
```

You get the desired clicked value.